# nth-child() being read wrong in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

The code I am putting in:

```
.binary_area .radio_option_container:nth-child(1) .radio_selection{...}
```

How IE11 is reading my code:

```
.binary_area:nth-child(1).radio_option_container .radio_selection{...}
```

This should be able to be replicated by pasting this directly into IE11, not using a simulator (as simulators are not always 100% accurate). Any ideas?

**Update**: I checked for browser compatibility & I am getting conflicting answers. Some sources say that this selector is not comparable other say the opposite.

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127342(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)
- [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of)

Comment: Please post all relevant code. We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 is the CanIUse for the normal :nth-child() selector. You linked a CanIUse for some new (more advanced) functionality.  If you want an answer replicate a simplified version of the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: A [quick and dirty test](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f53khsmt/) doesn't show any differences between IE11 and the other browsers.

Comment: Need full code to replicate and diagnose, bro

Comment: So you mean, on top of removing the descendant combinator, IE is also rewriting one of your class selectors willy nilly (.radio_option_container to .radio_option**s**_container)?

Comment: I have provided all the information I can think to & laid it out in as clear of a manner as I can think of. It is a very easy thing to recreate if one just does so. As believe that I state above, the issue I am having is recreatable by copying my selector & pasting it into IE11 DevTools. @BoltClock, no it does not rewrite my class, that was a typo, I should thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what parameters you are passing in your CSS and it would be helpful to see your HTML. There could be a discrepancy in what HTML elements you are trying to style (like a radio button) and maybe not just totally related to the CSS.

Comment: you are not telling us the facts of the "problem", instead you are trying to interpret the cause of the problem - which is not helpful to either of us. In case you are being handed a different element on IE rather than what others are returning - it is a characteristic signal that there are errors in your HTML code and that it time to run a check in html validator. IE has a more advanced error correction engine and doesn't ignore or pass through before correcting them. And of course make sure you don't mix html with xhml syntax or try "close" void elements as in <img />. That's wrong!